# Geometrical proof that product of two numbers both relatively prime to $n$ is also relatively prime to $n$

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I wonder if there is an elementary and geometrical proof of the following very basic fact.

Let $(k, n) = 1$ and $(a, n) = 1$ for some $a, k, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, it is also $(ak, n) = 1.$ (This is obviously connected with Euler's theorem whose proof I relearned yesterday for some reason.)

I tried this with lines (gcd of two lines, $x, y$, would then be the "longest" line which fits "nicely" in both lines $x, y$), but I cannot find obvious geometrical way to show this.

I would prefer you prove this with lines, because maybe I am missing something obvious, but other geometrical (visual) methods are also just fine.

I observed that I just love to torture myself with this kind of questions. :/

Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I don't think so, dear friend. However I like your position face to maths.

Comment: Hard to imagine geometrically distinguishing between lines that represent $[(10) :: (8)]$, $[(10) :: (7)]$, $[(10) :: (7.5)]$, and $[(10) :: (\sqrt{55})]$,

Comment: @user2661923, unfortunately, I don't understand a letter you wrote...

Comment: Your asking how to geometrically show that (for example) $(10,8)$ are not relatively prime, while $(10,7)$ are relatively prime.  You suggested doing this with lines, which means that you would somehow have to show that there is some common length that [1] represents an integer, [2] geometrically fits a whole number of times into both the line of length $(8)$ and the line of length $(10)$.  ...see next comment

Comment: In order to make this happen, you would have to **geometrically** distinguish between comparing $(10,8)$ and comparing $(10,k)$, where $(k)$ is one of the other values that I mentioned: $\{7, 7.5, \sqrt{55}\}.$  I don't see how you will be able to draw the necessary distinctions, by purely geometric methods.  A similar challenge would be to geometrically distinguish between comparing $(10,8)$ and comparing $(10, \frac{10}{3}).$

Comment: One approach that may be feasible is to assign a specific length as $(1)$ unit.  Then, you might insist that the geometric comparisons only apply to $(a,b)$ for which the $(1)$ unit length fits a *whole* number of times (i.e. $a,b$ are positive integers).  Then, since the gcd$(a,b)$ is computable via the Euclidean algorithm, you could *re-enact* the Euclidean algorithm geometrically.  Eventually, you will get a *remainder* equal $0$.  Then, the issue will be whether the just prior remainder was equal to the unit length, or was greater than the unit length.

Comment: Well, $n = 1 \cdot n$ while $\sqrt{55}$ is not. (I see it as a union of blocks with natural units, i. e. natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ of added lines with lenght $m \in \mathbb{N}$). Viewing it as blocks is distingusihing between pure line with no measure and something more concrete. I hope I am not on the wrong track with your comment...

Comment: see my last comment.

Comment: Yes, just set some specific lenght = 1 and then calculate other numbers (lines) with it.

Comment: Suppose $|k| = 18 \cdot 1, |n| = 35 \cdot 1.$ Obviously we know that $(|k|, |n|) = 1.$ But, if we have for example $|a| = 7$, then $ab = ba$ so we have $7 \cdot 18$ therefore 7 fits obviously into $ab$ natural number of times, hence $(a, n) = 7 > 1.$ How to do this when $(a, n) = 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider lines with lenghts $k = 18 \cdot 1$, $n = 245 \cdot 1, a = 24 \cdot 1.$ We can prove, case by case,  that line with maximal lenght that divides $k, n$ is the unit lenght. Simillary for $a, n.$

In other words, we know $(k, n) = (a, n) = 1.$

Now, consider line $p$ with lenght $ak = 24 \cdot 18$. We can visualize this as 24 distinct segments of line $p$ with each has $18$ unit lenghts. So, 24 sublines (groups) of 18 objects - unit lengths. Now, suppose $(a, n) = d > 1.$

We have 3 cases.

1. $1 < d < 18$. Now it must be $d | 18$ or $d | 24$ because otherwise $d$ would not divide $p$. Namely, if $d$ does not divide $18$ then $2d$ $3d, 4d, ...$, must reach endpoints of $18 \cdot 1$,
   or $18 \cdot 2$, ..., or $18 \cdot 24$ (divisors of $24$) - if not $d$ obviously wouldn't divide $p$. But then such maximal $d$ would be in form $18 \cdot 1$ or $18 \cdot 2$, ..., or $18 \cdot 24$ which is greater than 18, which gives contradiction. (And obviously $18 \cdot a = a \cdot 18$ can't divide $n = 245$.)
2. $d = 18$. This obviously doesn't work because $(18, 245) = 1$.
3. $d > 18.$ Obviously, $d$ must be in form $d = a \cdot 18$ where $a | 24$. (So, $d$ cannot be for example $20$ because then $d$ would not divide $p$). But then $d$ cannot divide $n = 245$ because $(a, n) = 1$. Contradiction.

Basically, in each case $d$ must be in form $k \cdot l, l \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., a\}$ which is not possible to do because $kl | a$ but $kl = l \cdot k$ can't fit nicely into $n$ because $k$ can't in the first place - so can't any multiple of it.

It must be $d = 1$. Therefore $(ak, n) = 1$.

I used only lengths and visual arguments here (divisors as groups of lenghts or groups of groups of lenghts - this would be analogous to factorization in arithmetic).

EDIT. Wow, Euclid also thought about this. His proof:
[https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/propVII24.html](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookVII/propVII24.html).